# How to submit multiple extrinsics in the same block in substrate? (RpcError: 1014: Priority is too low:)

Tags: substrate

I created a simple pallet using substrate. I am able to submit extrinsic using the RPC using the [substrate-front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template).

After submitting the extrinsic, I can see the transaction status as shown below

1. Current transaction status: Broadcast
2. Current transaction status: InBlock
3. ❤️️ Transaction successful! tx hash: 0x808d1a539a9d716203215202d7f9fb7ce10c9696e9449b355ea668871e3e0198 , Block hash: 0x5e95f78444121d0ed46f84d6fa903cac6a5ac58d873c6292a3d73e280f2c75ce

But when I try to submit a new extrinsic while the previous transaction status is `Broadcast` I am seeing the following error.

> Transaction Failed: RpcError: 1014: Priority is too low: (22861 vs 22861): The transaction has too low priority to replace another transaction already in the pool.

I can submit a new extrinsic successfully when the previous transaction is InBlock or successful state.

After digging deeper into why this happens,

I found that each substrate transaction will have two vectors `requires` and `provides`. Both contain `TransactionTag` (vector of bytes). `requires` is the list of tags to be already present in the ready pool for the current transaction to be included in the block and `provides` is the list of tags that the current transaction is providing. [Transaction](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/0d3c67d96beda62b729e8328c5755358ac244246/substrate/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/base_pool.rs#L88)

In [ready.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/0d3c67d96beda62b729e8328c5755358ac244246/substrate/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/ready.rs#L421C5-L421C21) in `sc-transaction-pool`, when a new transaction is being imported it is clearing the existing transactions which are providing tags that overlap with the `provides` tags from the current transaction.

I printed the `provides` tags for the extrinsics I submitted from the UI.
When I submit a new extrinsic,

1. If the previous transaction is in `Broadcast` state, the `provides` tag for the new extrinsic is same as the `provides` tag for previous transaction and I am getting the above error.
2. If the previous transaction is in `InBlock` or success state, the `provides` tag of the new extrinsic is different from `provides` tag of previous transaction (I guess nonce is changed) and there is no error.

I am guessing when the previous transaction is in `Broadcast`, the nonce is not updated yet and so the transaction tag. Is there any way to be able to submit new extrinsic even when the previous transaction state is `Broadcast`?

edit: 2023-11-06

The `provides` for a transaction is generated by combining the `provides` created by each of the structs declared here (all of which implement the SignedExtension triat)

```rs
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
pallet_asset_conversion_tx_payment::ChargeAssetTxPayment<Runtime>,
);
```

Among the above structs, only `CheckNonce` is actually creating `provides` and `requires`. That is the only thing that is changed in the transaction tag is the nonce for new transactions which I observed in the logs as well as shown below (the last 4 bytes are changed)

```
provides: [[212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
provides: [[212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
provides: [[212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My guess is that the `nonce` is not updated yet when the transaction is in `Broadcast` state and is being updated only when the transaction is in `InBlock` state. Now I am trying to figure out how to update the `nonce` after submitting the extrinsic so that the `provides` tag is different for the new extrinsic.

`inc_account_nonce` method is used to increment the nonce in the runtime storage. But I don't see it being called from anywhere else (apart from test files). [inc_account_nonce search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aparitytech%2Fpolkadot-sdk+inc_account_nonce&type=code)

Please feel free to ask any questions or context if not clear.